# Define udev rule for disk by id or uuid?

Tags: linux, udev, devices, block-device, filter

I want to define a udev rule for a particular block device (or partition). I currently do it by defining a `91-my-custom-rules.rules` configuration file as follows:

```
computer:/etc/udev/rules.d # cat 91-my-custom-rules.rules 
KERNEL=="sdc2", OWNER="username", GROUP="users", MODE="0600"
```

The above example changes the ownership of `/dev/sdc2` to `username:users` and sets its permissions to `0600`.

For obvious reasons, `/dev/sdc2` might not always point to the exact same device/partition. Therefore, I'd like to define a rule for a disk by id or uuid instead. How can I do this?

Comment: Other than using the other attributes of the device?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams As long as I can reliably filter for the right device, I do not care how it it's done. I thought disk ids or uuids make most sense, though.

Comment: Try matching on `ENV{ID_FS_UUID}`

Answer (score 3):

For the same purpose I created a file /etc/udev/rules.d/60-sda.rules with content

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", \
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="Generic_Ultra_HS-SD_MMC_000000264131-0:0", \
SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/sd-mux-ctrl-0", GROUP="sd-mux-ctrl"
```

It creates a symbolic link /dev/by-id/sd-mux-ctrl-0 for the device with serial number 'Generic_Ultra_HS-SD_MMC_000000264131-0:0' and assigns group sd-mux-ctrl to the target of the symbolic link.

As the serial number is retained after reformatting I prefer this solution to relying on a UUID.